# Is there a Notification Monitoring Capability for Firebase?

Tags: firebase, push-notification

Is there a capability (function/app) for developers to monitor the receipt of a specific Firebase notification (a message now), actions by Firebase on it and perhaps reactions of the destination to it?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It did push me down that path, including adding an analysis label, but didn't reveal anything new, just validated that Firebase didn't think it had received a single message from Azure to forward.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the Firebase console offers that capability, as it only reports aggregates.

But from a quick check it seems that the optional [export of delivery data to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery#bigquery-data-export) contains both the `message_id` of the message and the `instance_id` of the instance it's delivered to, so you should be able to check it there.